# Remove staircase in this example

Tags: css

Is it possible to remove the staircase effect in this example ? I have one div floating right and a few divs with fixed height and fixed width floating left. If the divs meet somewhere I get a rather strange staircase effect.

I know why this happens and I get it but im looking for a solution to avoid this. Please help me

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="fright">just some contents floating right</div>
  <div class="fleft">a div</div>
  <div class="fleft">
        this one is the problem. 
        Is it possible to have this div start at position B
  </div>
  <div class="fleft"><b>Position B</b></div>
  <div class="fleft">a div</div>
</div>
```

​
and the css

```
div{
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;


.container{
    width:460px;
    float:left;
}

.fright{
    float:right;
    border:1px solid green;
}

.fleft{
    float:left;
    height:180px;
    width:180px;
    border:1px solid orange;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FusWd/1/

Comment: Can you make an example of how you want it to turn out?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using floats, you may want to try using inline-block to do your layout.

I've updated your example here : http://jsfiddle.net/FusWd/4/

There are some caveats with this technique:

- IE 6-7 doesn't support inline-block, you'll have to use the 'hasLayout' trick.
- inline-block elements are influenced by whitespace in your markup, which may or may not break your layout. There are a couple of solutions to this.

  - You can remove the whitespace between the inline block elements in your markup
  - set the parent element's font-size and line-height to 0, and the letter-spacing and word-spacing properties to -1px, then reset font-size and line-height to their desired values, and reset letter-spacing and word-spacing properties to the `normal` values.

Comment: No problem. If an answer is useful to you, you should mark it as an accepted answer. Read more about the conventions of stackoverflow here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask